# windows server: top-level domain DNS LAN configuration

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2012

I am trying to configure the DNS service of a Windows server. The LAN hosts should all be assigned the top-level domain ".lan".

Where do I implement this in the DNS configuration GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a zone for `lan` and add the `A` and `AAAA`records for your equipment. Then configure the clients to use this DNS.

Unless you are using Active Directory and your DNS is a DC for the domain called `lan`, adding hosts to the DNS zone will not be automatic. I think you can set up the DHCP role of Winodws Server to update DNS, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! I have learnt that the name of the zone should be the top domain of choice (here: "lan"). I have a followup question though. Is it advisable to create a reverse-lookup zone for the internal LAN as well?

Comment: That will be useful only if you need for an app to find the name of the machine that has a specific IP. On a LAN, especially a small one, it is utterly useless.

Comment: You shouldn't do before you find that you need one. You'll have enough work taking care of the direct lookup zone.